# How to show read prompt with a new line

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using `read` builtin to read a variable, but I'd like to let the input appears on the next line, that is, the prompt output a new line, but neither of the two works:

```
$ read -p "Please input:\n" name
Please input:\n

$ read -p 'Please input:\n" name
Please input:\n
```

As you see new line escape sequence is not interpreted even in the double quote case. So is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate the prompt from the actual read :

```
echo "Please input:"
read name
```

You can put both on a single line :

```
echo "Please input:" ; read name
```

You can also use a different form of quoting :

```
read -p $'Please input\n' name
```

This is barely shorter, and many would probably find it a bit less readable, but that is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, but this is two lines of two commands, I wonder if I can do that with just read?

Comment: Please see additional suggestions.  I would go with two separate (but simpler) commands, but it is only a matter of preference.